# Downloading full facebook friends list

Tags: facebook

I'm writing IM that connects to Facebook (via XMPP). I have a little problem with new Facebook API which allows to me to download information about only these users who are using my app. Well, to create full contacts list I have to download full users list. Is there any workaround other than downloading full website and regexing it?

Comment: You are aware that the XMPP API will be removed with API v2.0 at 4/30/2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no workaround. You are not supposed to download data of users who did not authorize your App for privacy reasons.

Also, the Chat API will stop working after April 2015, so it´s pointless to use it for any new App. There is no alternative as of now.